# Database design: multiple potential identifiers

Tags: database-design

When creating a `Funds` or `Assets` table, I am often confronted with the same problem: not all `Assets` have the same identifier.

Eg: 70% have an `ISIN`, some have a bloomberg code, some have both, some only have an `AccountingID` coming from the local accounting package, and so on.

Generally I end up by giving that table a surrogate PK, plus distinct fields for all the possible identifiers (`Bloomberg, ISIN, AccoutingID`,..)

I once inherited such a database where the developer had migrated the alternate keys to a child table [Identifiers], based on the fact that he did not know in advance every possible alternate key.

This Identifiers table looked like this:

- `AssetID` (the surrogate one)
- `IdentifierType` (e.g: ISIN)
- `IdValue`

**What is the best solution ?**

I think the first (single table) is best because, even if I risk having a few Nulls, an ISIN is an ISIN and is well defined attribute of the `Fund`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do single table because the Identifiers table method makes assumptions about the datatype of the idValue. What if you get something new that uses a guid rather than an int?

You could still do a separate column for each possible asset ID and keep the data about the assets in a separate table that keys off the surrogate ID. The approach you take will depend mainly on how you will use the data, and how often you might add new asset ID types.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little on your needs but the second approach is often more flexible as you can provide a sensible interface to insert a new 'Identifier' record which doesn't require a database schema change.

This would normally be used if you don't know how many identifiers could exist, or if you knew you needed to add more over time.

The former approach is simpler in terms of writing queries and if the identifiers are static is probably easiest to use.

Comment: +1 for future proofing.  I never trust external identifiers as primary keys.  If someone else has control of them then they have no motivation to keep your system stable by leaving the values alone.  Isolating the multiple external identifiers allows for easy, consistent retrieval while remaining flexible for future changes.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree, the type of de-normalism described by putting identifiers in with the related entity should probably only be used if you know it will not change, or a singular relationship to the entity.

Comment: @Joel Brown: solution 1 (single table) does not imply using the external identifiers as PK ! I mentionned using a surrogate PK.

Comment: @iDevlop - Understood, but the thing that makes external identifiers dicey as PK's - your inability to control them - makes them risky as dedicated attributes of an entity too.  That's why a situation like yours, where there are multiple candidate keys based on external identifiers stikes me as a pretty good candidate for EAV.