# How to design database using varying number of columns in table

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

Let us say that you are creating a system to store characteristics of different countries. There will be same basic columns like name, population, capital city etc. But let us say in addition to it you want to store some country specific information like highest mountain, nearest ocean, most famous food etc. These columns will be different for each country.

How can this be done using a relational database like MySQL.
I know this is easier using a schema-less NoSQL database like MongoDB where each country can be stored as a separate document. But can something like this be done using relational DBs?

Comment: you have to create 2 additional tables. first is a list of items (`id, title`) = (1, 'Highest mountain') and the second table is used to store values for countries - (`itemId,countryId, value`)

Comment: @gaurav: I don't think the tag nosql is appropriate for an rdbms related question...

Comment: @iDevlop - Thanks, I removed the nosql tag.

Comment: While I think all the answers suggesting the [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) approach (didn't know that term, thx @iDevlop) are correct I would most times prefer a single table with lots of null values. Highly normalized schemas tend to have a rather bad impact on performance, but this also depends on usage patterns. Maybe a combination is the best approach: a main table with the most common attributes and additional tables for additional attribute-value pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With only text fields you need two additional tables:

- properties (contains the name of a property, eg "highest mountain")
- country_properties (contains values for country-property pairs: eg: id of country "austria", id of property "highest mountain", "name of the mountain")

Alternatively, if there are only a couple of properties, simply store NULL for unknown values.

Comment: if you also have integer or float values you can store `fieldType` column in `properties` table and then you may add 3 columns to `values` table as (propId, countryId, charValue, intValue, floatValue)

Answer (score 3):

It can.  As I learned today by asking [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9415091/78522), this is called EAV (for Entity-Attribute-Value model). I found an interesting explanation about it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a **Super-Type** - **Sub-Type** of a data structure. The **Super-Type** is what is common amongst all the data (in your case Countries). The **Sub-Type** is what is unique to each group of data (in your case countries). You would have **one super-type table** and **several sub-type tables**. The sub-type tables contain Foreign Keys that link back to the super-type table.

This lets you query all by **super-type** and then do a drill down by **sub-type**.

**Subtypes** that come to mind for countries are:
Mountanous
LandLocked
OceanView

You could even sub them out by continent:
NorthAmerica
SouthAmerica
Asia
Oceania

Answer (score 0):

You are really not supposed to be doing that with a standard relational database. Instead store the extra data in separate tables and use a foreign key referencing the country table.

Having columns that are only sometimes used is generally a violation of relational integrety. Sometimes it's neccessary for performance reasons, but if that is not a concern to you I would highly suggest going with the most appropriate relational model.

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are truly different for each country, then create a new table called country_field with the following columns

- country_id  (FK to your country table)
- field_name  varchar
- field_value varchar

Store your country specific attributes in this table with one row for each country specific field.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario with an app requiring mySQL, what I found the most flexable option was for us was to split the data into multiple tables, for example we may have a table called `country_register` that has

```
country_id (int primary key) | country_name
```

Then we have another table called say `country_data` that has

```
tbl_id (int primary key) | country_id (int foreign key) | country_property (varchar index) | country_data (text indexed as fulltext)
```

Basically the `country_property` is a reference for you to get data out, so it could be for example "population" and the `country_data` would then have the actual data you want.

You would then use a `JOIN` and each row will have all of the data you need. This is the most flexible structure using mySQL I know of and it works well for these types of tasks.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the mountains as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `mountains` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255),
  `height` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_country_id` (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You can than create a `SELECT`-query, to get the highest mountain of each country, by doing something like:

```
SELECT c.name, m.name, MAX(m.height) as height
FROM mountains m
JOIN countries c
ON c.id = m.country_id
GROUP BY m.country_id;
```

Comment: will you create separate table for each entity?  mountain, river, ocean, food and so on? 
it is good approach if you have only few entities.. but in this case it isn't. imho.

Comment: I didn't want to down vote this, but in my opinion this design is very bad. I know this is an old topic, but in case people like me find this specific answer later: don't do this.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky: Maybe its a good idea to show us why you think this design is bad. I like to learn from my mistakes aswell.

Comment: This method requires creating tables for every property. A property is a type, which should be used a column not a table on it's own. The question states that each country might not have that property. So in a column based design, that cell's value should be null. Your design also does not take the factor of building the queries. The dba would have to create a join statement for each table. For example 20 properties for a country would have 20 joins, and since each table is it's own file MySQL would need to use a lot of memory and CPU cycles just to compute the conditions of the join.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have three strategies:

1. Full-meta design, the values of nullable attributes for countries would be put into value-collection table. For example:

   country(country_id, non-null-attr-1, non-null-attr-2, non-null-attr-....)
   meta_attr(attr_id, attr_desc)(may more complex if you need I18N)
   attr_value(country_id, attr_id, attr_value)
2. Partially meta design, using sub-class of table to reference the main table of country. Such method is usable if you could classify a certain data instance to a collection of non-null attributes. For example:

   country(country_id, non-null-attr-1, non-null-attr-2, non-null-attr-....)
   specific_type_country(country_id, non-null-attr-1, non-null-attr-2, non-null-attr-...)
3. All attributes in main table of countries, this method is only viable if your don't need to add new attribute into country from system. For example:

   country(country_id, non-null-attr-1, non-null-attr-2, non-null-attr-...., nullable-attr-1, nullable-2, nullable-attr-...)

When I am designing under such scenario, I used to consider the performance of queries running on such data.

If the queries are the list of countries for all possible attributes, using No.3 is better.

If the queries target a certain classes of countries, say, a list of countries have nearest ocean(which this attribute can't be null). No.2 is better.

If the queries need the detail information for a country at a time, No.1 is better.

Of course, you may mix any of above three strategies to design a suitable solution for your possible queries.

---

Assume that the "most famous food"(nullable) would be needed on whatever queries, put this attribute into main table of country.

Assume that the "nearest ocean" is needed in a few of queries, put this attribute into sub-class of country table.

Assume that the "highest mountain name", "The average temperature of highest mountain" is needed for queries that retrieve only one row at most(say, queried by primary key), put this attribute into meta-table.